# Meaning of + symbol with Strings in Java println statement

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. What does the below mean?

> (addition) + sign in **println**
>
> **System.out.println ("Count is: " + i);**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plus operator has a double meaning. Its a concatination operator as well. As the "Count is:" is of type `String` the "i" (`Integer`?) is converted to a `String` as well.

I haven't read it as I prefer reference books, however some really like the Book [Head First Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) as it seems to explain concepts.

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly what it does outside the println method, id adds to objects:

if the objects are Strings it concatenates them:

```
"hello" + "world" --> "helloworld"
```

if the objects are numbers it adds the UNLESS there's a String to the left (or at least a String with higher precedence).

```
2 + 4 + "hello" --> "6hello"

"hello" + 2 + 4 --> "hello24"

"hello" + (2 + 4) --> "hello6"
```

if the object is any thing else it will treat them as Strings using the `toString()` method

Answer (score 0):

`+` is string concatenation operator and it is used for `conversion` of other objects to strings (based upon the implementation of toString() method) and also `concatenate` two strings.

```
String str1="Hello";
String str2="World"

String result=str1 + " " + str2;
```

Answer (score 0):

When one of the operands to `+` is a String, the java compiler converts the other argument to a string too, and concatenates them into a new string.

If `i` is 1 the result is "Count is: " + "1" which is "Count is: 1"

Answer (score 0):

The + sign in the context of strings is the [concatenation operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). It joins two strings together.

E.g.

```
String str = "hello" + "world";
```

would result in a String object called str, with a value of "**helloworld**".

Answer (score 0):

The + in arithmetic adds 2 numbers together, like this:

```
2 + 2 = 4
```

now apply the same thing to a string:

```
"hello " + "world!" = "hello world!"
```

now adding strings and variables will do this:

```
int number = 4;
String string = "what was the number? oh yeah: "+number;
System.out.println(string);
```

if all goes well you should get "what was the number? oh yeah: 4"

Java took the value of the variable and put it into the string for you, hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

In *that context*, the `+` operator is acting as the **string concatenation operator**. It acts as a different operator in the context of two integral types, where addition will be performed.

Assuming `i` is an integral type, it'll be converted to a `String` and then added on to the end of a *new* string beginning with `"Count is: "`. That new string is then printed.

ie. If `i` had the value `0`, it'd be the same as:

```
"Count is: " + "0"
```

Which would be:

```
"Count is: 0"
```